# is it possible to FTP a rails app to a linux server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, hosting, vps

I have a 1and1 Linux VPS server and we are not permitted to use third party applications like Github to push our code to the server. I realise that this is silly but nevertheless.

Is it actually possible to get a Rails app running by FTPing it over to a Linux server?

Comment: how would you setup/start/restart your rails app? for that you need something like SSH or some management systems in you customers panel or something like that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What exactly are you looking to do? Access a rails application via ftp rather than http? Transfer a rails app to a linux server via ftp?

Comment: so basically im looking to upload a rails site to a preconfigured linux server. I am aware of installing all of the dependencies like mysql, rvm etc via SSH which is fine. I just want to manually upload the files to a space in the server, transfer a rails app to a linux server via ftp.

Comment: There is a much easier way: Give heroku a try and you'll be up and running in a few minutes. Here's a [quickstart guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3) and [another one](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html). It's free if you need only one process (they call it dyno).

Comment: Of course you're able to transfer a rails app through FTP. You can send it anyway you want! However, you'll need ruby installed on your preconfigured server. Just zip up your folder, ftp it over and then unzip.

Comment: Thomas - I use heroku for personal stuff, and i wish we could use it!! so easy. Sunny J, seems to good to be true lol

Comment: "Just zip up your folder, ftp it over and then unzip." That assumes shell access. Many FTP clients allow sending the contents of a directory or hierarchy which will substitute nicely if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, this is possible. You'd copy all the files over. Only a couple tricky points:

- Setting environmental variables might be difficult
- Depends on what application server 1&1 provides to you. Apache by itself isn't good enough, you'll need something to run the Ruby code, like Passenger, Mongrel (old but possibly available), or Unicorn (unlikely).

Also --- you have a VPS server, so you probably have SSH access and can use ssh to copy files up, rather than FTP.

Capistratno setup:

```
set :repository, "."
set :scm, :none
set :deploy_via, :copy
```

Comment: what kind of environment variables? I am happy enough installing another webserver and other dependencies via SSH. The 1and1 server comes with apache, ubuntu 64bit 10.4 and mysql built in.

Comment: if you have full control, then use ssh copying an capistrano.. updated with that setup.

Comment: hmm I'm not certain that capistrano will be an option as its considered another third party tool and bypasses ftp, which is massively rubbish! If its possible to just ftp then thats great. I presume you setup a space on the server as you would do normally via ssh and then ftp to that destination?

Comment: but yes, if you can login to the server and install Passenger. Then whenever you deploy, you can delete and create a tmp/restart.txt and passenger will reload your newly ftp'd code.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jesse, its ridiculous i know. myb ill start playing golf again lol